# Have to render a react component based on props that changes a js variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have imported the Dice icon components from react-icons, but I want them to render according to props passed from the Dice component. So, I have created a js variable inside Dice.js to get the icon name, but while trying to render the icon component, the icon is not getting displayed but only the name is getting displayed. Below is the code:

App.js:

```
import "./styles.css";
import Dice from './Dice';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      Roll the Dice
      <Dice dice='One'/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Dice.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  FaDiceOne,
  FaDiceTwo,
  FaDiceThree,
  FaDiceFour,
  FaDiceFive,
  FaDiceSix
} from "react-icons/fa";

class Dice extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    
  }

  render() {

    let randomDice = `FaDice${this.props.dice}`;
    console.log(randomDice);
    
    return (
      <div className="Dice">
        <randomDice/>
        <FaDiceTwo/>
        <FaDiceThree/>
        <FaDiceFour/>
        <FaDiceFive/>
        <FaDiceSix/>
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dice;
```

I am not able to render randomDice variable as react-icon component. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an object, e.g:

```
const IconsByDice = {
  one: <FaDiceOne />,
  two: <FaDiceTwo />
  .....ans so on ....
};
```

And render a component:

```
<div className="Dice">
 {IconsByDice[this.props.dice]}
  <FaDiceTwo/>
 ..... and so on ....
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's working . Can you help me in finding out the mistake in my code

Comment: You're trying to render a component called `randomDice`, which doesn't exist. `randomDice` is treated as a string, not as a variable.

Comment: Ohh, got it now. Thank you 

Comment: Glad to help :) Please accept my answer if it helped you :)